# SQL Function, COALESCE & Sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetTrustNotesByTrustIDForAdminConsole] 
( @TrustID INT
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + '|' , '') + ltrim(Note.NoteText)
    FROM   TrustNote
    JOIN   Note 
    ON     TrustNote.NoteID = Note.NoteID
    and    Note.Archived = 0
    WHERE  Trustid = @TrustID

    RETURN @listStr

END
```

This function returns "Notes" from the database and compiles them, however there is a  another column in Note (Note.ListOrderNumber) that I would like to sort by in addition to coalesce.

I know it doesn't work to just add in an order by prior to returning, but is there a way to add this in?

## EXAMPLE DATA

```
Note 1, Position 2
Note 2, Position 3
Note 3, Position 1
```

Currently retrieves exactly as stated there.
Adding `ORDER BY Note.ListOrderNumber` after the Where clause only produces a single result:

```
Note 2, Position 3
```

Comment: Try adding the `ORDER BY` clause after the `WHERE` clause, I can't test it but I am fairly sure it will work.

Comment: Guido, PLEASE Do not remove `dbo` in code here, especially in `ALTER FUNCTION` statements.  Just because `dbo` is the default schema for users doesn't mean the current user doesn't have and is not currently using his or her own schema!  It's good practice to always denote the schema at least in the name of the stored proc or function being altered!

Comment: (The above message was for a previous editor, sorry.)

Comment: Couldn't you just do it as a subquery, so you order it and then select the note text from your subquery?

Comment: I just put all of this into SQL Server 2008 and I'm getting all the rows and getting them ordered when I include the order by statement:
`Note 3, Position 1|Note 1, Position 2|Note 2, Position 3`

What version of SQL Server are you using and is there anything additional you're leaving out?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is currently returning a VARCHAR(MAX) - and the SELECT statement sets the variable to 1 rows fields (probably the first row).  This will always return 1 varchar field.  If you wish to return all the rows you must either do one of two things (depends on how this fits into your other code as you may need to change the calling procedure):

Option 1: 
Create a cursor and loop through your SELECT statement and keep appending to the variable @liststr 
This will then still return one long string

Option 2:
Change the function to return a table
eg:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetTrustNotesByTrustIDForAdminConsole] 
( @TrustID INT
)
RETURNS @Temp TABLE(
  lstStr varchar(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO @Temp(lstStr)
  SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + '|' , '') + ltrim(Note.NoteText)
  FROM   TrustNote
  JOIN   Note 
  ON     TrustNote.NoteID = Note.NoteID
  AND    Note.Archived = 0
  WHERE  Trustid = @TrustID

  RETURN

END
```

Answer (score 0):

That approach to concatenate strings does not always work as expected.

[PRB: Execution Plan and Results of Aggregate Concatenation Queries Depend Upon Expression Location](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515)

Use `for xml` instead.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetTrustNotesByTrustIDForAdminConsole] 
( @TrustID INT
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @listStr = 
      (
      SELECT   '|'+Note.NoteText
      FROM     TrustNote
      JOIN     Note 
      ON       TrustNote.NoteID = Note.NoteID
      and      Note.Archived = 0
      WHERE    Trustid = @TrustID
      ORDER BY Note.ListOrderNumber
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)')

    RETURN STUFF(@listStr, 1, 1, '')

END
```